# Are Loan words still compound?

Tags: compounds, loanwords, foreign-phrases

English imports lots of foreign words. If those words are compound in their original language, do we still consider them compound in English?

Examples

- Kindergarten
- Chickpea
- ???

Comment: I wouldn't call *chickpea* a loan word.

Comment: The _chick_ part comes from Latin, and the _pea_ part is English. It's the installment plan.

Comment: Guessing : (1) If the loanword is made of 2 or more "Parts" of which at least 1 is Individually a loanword or a word , then it can be argued that we have a compound word. (2) If none of the "Constituents" of the loanword are loanwords (or words) themselves , then we do not have a compound word.

Comment: Why does it matter if they're compound? Are you interested in some particular facet like hyphenation? We can argue whether individual words are compounds, but they may be compound in one sense and not in another sense.

Comment: @StuartF I was interested if there was a general rule for this.

Comment: I would not know. I assume compound words are adopted as such i.e. if it were two words in the parent language, it would be two words in English; hyphenated would be hyphenated; single would be single. If it were not a compound word in parent language or if it is a new word created from words from two or more languages, then I would assume no rules apply. It would what the earliest users decide. Maybe Lawler, Bunting, Stuart and other expert forum members would be able to help you with that

Comment: I would ask this on [Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com), seeing as you've had no answers here. :)